# How do I configure devise to use a custom email layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mailer

When I say layout I don't mean just simply the views, I generate those. On all my own mailers I'm using a default layout. Which I define in the SomeMailer.rb file

```
#some_mailer.rb
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'sometemplate'
```

Is there some way I can do this for the Devise Mailer et al.?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Found the answer sitting in the Devise Github wiki,

Reading that helps. ;-)

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::Mailer.layout "simple" # simple.haml or simple.erb
  Devise::Mailer.helper :mailer
end
```

Here is the reference of the wiki page: [How To: Create custom layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `Devise::Mailer.layout "simple"` to the top of your `devise.rb` initializer, before the setup block.

Comment: Could you clarify what `# email.haml or email.erb` means? Did you mean to write `# simple.haml or simple.erb `?

Comment: Fixed. (The comment should be `# simple.haml or simple.erb` — it's been copied and pasted from the referenced Devise wiki but only the string `"simple"` was customised.)

Comment: Use only ```Devise::Mailer.layout "simple"``` . config.to_prepare raises an error in later gem versions.

Comment: This answer is still valid for Devise 3.5, though could use some more information. Note that the `config.to_prepare` needs to go in your `application.rb`, or you can use `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` in `devise.rb`. The link goes into a good amount of detail.

Comment: @leppert your comment deserves to be an answer, maybe a top-rated and accepted one as well..

Answer (score 45):

There is also a *parent_mailer* option in **devise.rb**, let's say you are sending emails outside of devise, by default this option is set to **ActionMailer::Base**, but if you have an **ApplicationMailer** that already is inheriting from **ActionMailer::Base**, you could change *parent_mailer* to this and get all your **layouts** and **configurations** out of the box.

In any case is a lot cleaner to use this to keep the rails flow of layouts in your applications if you don't want to change anything in the devise mailer controller.

```
# devise.rb
config.parent_mailer = 'ApplicationMailer'
```

---

```
# application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    layout 'mailer'
end
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 20):

```
# Devise::Mailer inherits from ActionMailer::Base other mail will work fine.

## app/mailers/deviser_mailer.rb

class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  layout 'email'
  default from: I18n.t("mailer.default.from")
end

## then in config/initializer/devise.rb

# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
config.mailer = "DeviseMailer"
```

Make sure to restart your rails server as you changed an initializer.

Answer (score -3):

Try reopen Devise::Mailer class:

```
 class Devise::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
   layout 'sometemplate'
 end
```

Comment: didn't work.  I also tried several other variations on the Class, but they didn't override the devise template, or non-template